# I have a angular directive for kendo grid. My issue is ajax in my service fires only after the complete directive executes

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

My ajax fires after the complete directive executes. Is there any work around for this so that I can have my grid configuration loads before coming to the grid directive

```
gridApp.directive('grid', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {
            gridName: "@"
        },
        template: '<h1>kendoDirective</h1><br/><div kendo-grid={{gridName}} options="gridOptions"></div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, widgetUtils) {
            var gridConfig = widgetUtils.GetGridOption().then(onLoad);
            var onLoad = function (data) {
                $scope.gridOptions = data;
            }
            console.log('DirectiveScope: ' + $scope.gridOptions);
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        }
    };
});

gridApp.service('widgetUtils', function ($http) {
    var getGridOption = function () {
        return $http.get('/Base/LoadGridConfiguration').then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    return {
        GetGridOption: getGridOption
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with `ng-if` in template. I created `$scope.isReady` and change it state after options loaded.

```
gridApp.directive('grid', function () {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
        gridName: "@"
    },
    template: '<h1>kendoDirective</h1><br/><div data-ng-if="isReady" kendo-grid={{gridName}} options="gridOptions"></div>',
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, widgetUtils) {
        var gridConfig = widgetUtils.GetGridOption().then(onLoad);

        $scope.isReady = false;

        var onLoad = function (data) {
            $scope.gridOptions = data;

            $scope.isReady = true; // here we ready to init kendo component
            $scope.$apply();

        }
        console.log('DirectiveScope: ' + $scope.gridOptions);
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    }
 };
});
```

Comment: It didn't worked... I kept one console.log inside onLoad function and that was not executed. I only come to know that service is called is by looking in the network tab. Service works fine, only issue is that service is called when the directive is completely executed. Any other idea or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, what is `widgetUtils` then?

Comment: It's a service. It will make an ajax call to bring the grid configuration.

Comment: And it gets completed only when the directive is loaded.